# python: Quantile code is not changing the max and min values

Tags: python, dataframe, outliers

The following code is not making any changes when removing the outliers. What could be wrong with the code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random


df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.randint(0, 100000000, 50000),
                   'col_2':np.random.randint(0, 100000000, 50000)})

print('Max: ', df['price'].max())
print('Min: ', df['price'].min())
Q1 = df['price'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df['price'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1


df = df[~((df['price'] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df['price'] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)))]
print(df.shape)
print('Max: ', df['price'].max())
print('Min: ', df['price'].min())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your data doesn't have any outliers -- as per your definition.
If you generate some, as in the example below, they will be removed by your code as you would expect.

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.randint(0, 100000000, 50000), 
                    'col_2':np.random.randint(0, 100000000, 50000)}) 
      .append(pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.randint(100000000, 200000000, 50),  
                            'col_2':np.random.randint(0, 100000000, 50)})) 
      .reset_index(drop=True) 
     )
```